# webViewDidFinishLoad not being called with loadHTMLString

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

So this loads when the app launches

```
NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head>"
"<meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 200\"/></head>"
"<body style=\"background:#FFFFF;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\">"
"<div><object width=\"320\" height=\"200\">"
"<param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param>"
"<embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/%@&app=youtube_gdata\""
"type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"320\" height=\"200\"></embed>"
"</object></div></body></html>", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"detailVideoURL"]];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:youTubeVideoHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Althogh the `webViewDidFinishLoad` is not being called, does anyone have any idea why that's happening ?, I've already added the `UIWebViewDelegate`.

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get working with `UIWebViewDelegate` methods you to connect `UIWebView` delegate with the `File's Owner`....
[image]