# UIWebView Delegate : webViewDidFinishLoad not being called

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I try to load an array of UIWebView with delegate associated.

```
for (GDataXMLElement *post in array) {
    NSString *msg = [[[post elementsForName:@"message"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
    UIWebView *web_view = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    web_view.delegate = self;
    [web_view loadHTMLString:msg baseURL:nil];
    NSLog(@"Msg: %@", msg);
}
```

where `msg` is some HTML codes reading from XML. XML is loaded properly (verified by the `NSLog` line). Then in my `webViewDidFinishLoad:`:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    CGRect frame = webView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    webView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    webView.frame = frame;
    NSLog(@"WebView Height: %.1f", webView.frame.size.height);

    [webviews addObject:webView];
}
```

I auto resize the web views and add them to a `NSMutableArray` called `webviews`. However, `webViewDidFinishLoad` is not called.

In the header `.h` file, the interface is defined as:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
```

What did I miss? Is the `web_view` in the loop get disposed ?

p.s. It looks like a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507450/webviewdidfinishload-not-being-called-with-loadhtmlstring), but it isn't.

---

**Alternate Approach 1**

Declared at `.h`:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSMutableArray *webviews;
```

Then for implementation:

```
for (GDataXMLElement *post in array) {
    NSString *msg = [[[post elementsForName:@"message"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
    UIWebView *web_view = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    web_view.delegate = self;
    [web_view loadHTMLString:msg baseURL:nil];
    NSLog(@"Msg: %@", msg);
    [self.webviews addObject:web_view];
}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    CGRect frame = webView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    webView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    webView.frame = frame;
    NSLog(@"WebView Height: %.1f", webView.frame.size.height);
}
```

---

**Alternate Approach 2**

Instead of instantiating `UIWebView` in `for-loop`, I put it in header file.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate> {
    UIWebView *web_view;
}
```

Then change the for-loop:

```
for (GDataXMLElement *post in array) {
    NSString *msg = [[[post elementsForName:@"message"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
    web_view = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    web_view.delegate = self;
    [web_view loadHTMLString:msg baseURL:nil];
    NSLog(@"Msg: %@", msg);
    [self.webviews addObject:web_view];
}
```

In this approach, only the delegate of last message gets called.

---

Summary & Highlights:

My objectives:

1. Load all `UIWebView` with variable-size contents
2. The web views should auto fit the size of contents ( without scrolling ); that's why `webViewDidFinishLoad` is required.
3. Arrange the web views properly on current view ( or probably a `UIScrollView` ) in order to make it not overlapped.

Comment: Declare UIWebView *web_view property at class level. It will resolve this problem.

Comment: Just tried. I added `web_view` to `.h`, still the same.

Comment: That should definitely work. Try cleaning project/removing build folder etc etc... It should work.

Comment: See "Alternative Approach 2" just added.

Comment: Try declaring property like @property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *web_view; and than use _web_view = [[UIWebView alloc]...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my final solution ( hope it is useful for others ):

In Storyboard, I added a `UIScrollView` in the view controller, and link it with the `IBOutlet`.

**Header file:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GDataXMLNode.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll_view;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *web_view;

@end
```

**Implementation file:**

```
float currentY;
NSArray *array;
int count;
GDataXMLDocument *doc;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    currentY = 0;
    count = 0;
    [self loadXML];
}

- (void)loadXML {
   // Some codes to load the XML contents into array variable
   [self loadWebView];
}

- (void)loadWebView {
    if(count < array.count) {
        GDataXMLElement *post = [array objectAtIndex:count];
        NSString *msg = [[[post elementsForName:@"message"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
        count++;
        self.web_view = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, currentY, 300, 1.0f)];
        self.web_view.delegate = self;
        [self.web_view setHidden:YES];
        [self.web_view loadHTMLString:msg baseURL:nil];
        [scroll_view addSubview:self.web_view];
    } else {
        // end the process
        [scroll_view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, currentY + 30)];
        return;
    }
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    CGRect frame = webView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    webView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    webView.frame = frame;
    [webView setHidden:NO];

    currentY += webView.frame.size.height + 20.0f; // 20.0f is spaces between posts

    NSLog(@"WebView Height: %.1f", webView.frame.size.height);
    [self loadWebView];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do like this,

```
@interface UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
{

}
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *webViews;

@end

////////////////

@implementation UIViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

   webViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   for (GDataXMLElement *post in array) 
   {
    NSString *msg = [[[post elementsForName:@"message"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
    UIWebView *web_view = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    web_view.delegate = self;
    [web_view loadHTMLString:msg baseURL:nil];
    NSLog(@"Msg: %@", msg);
    [self.webViews addObject:web_view];

     //i don't know why would  you not add these web-views on the view controller,
     // but still, here is the addition of these.
     [self.view addSubView:web_view];
    }
}

@end
```

This should make the web-views call the delegate properly on load.

Comment: I want to evaluate the content heights of the `UIWebView` before adding to current view. Your solution did not handle `webViewDidFinishLoad` at all.

Comment: You main problem was that the webView was not calling the webViewDidFinishLoad method. So my above code will make the web-views call the method for each web-view. You did not ask for finding a solution to evaluate height anywhere in your question. Edit your question and ask a solution to evaluate the heights of web-views too. So that someone can answer you on that including me.. :)

Comment: Edited the question; so can you give some lights?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ARC, the web_view is deallocated at the end of the for loop.

Comment: Yes, ARC is used, so what is the solution?

Comment: Please avoid posting one liner questions/instructions as answers.

Comment: You need to store the UIWebView somewhere in the ViewController, perhaps in an NSMutableArray property.

Comment: Tim, if you see the code, then he is already adding the WebView inside some array by "self.webViews addObject". Hence, the web-views generated in the loop will not be released at the end of loop.